# MediaRouter.sendControlRequest doesn't work

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm developing small android chromecast sender application. 
And when I'm trying to create new session using MediaRouter API it doesn't work.

```
import android.support.v7.media.MediaControlIntent;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;

class PlayerFragment extends Fragment 
{

MediaRoute.Callback cb;

/*
  ....
*/


cb = new MediaRouter.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteSelected(router, route);

            Log.v("PlayerFragment", "Route selected");
            mRoute = route;
            createSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteUnselected(router, route);

            mRoute = null;
        }
    };

private void startDiscovery(){
    mRouter.addCallback(selector, cb, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
}

private void createSession(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaControlIntent.ACTION_START_SESSION);

    intent.addCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK);

    intent.putExtra(CastMediaControlIntent.EXTRA_CAST_APPLICATION_ID,
            CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID);

    intent.putExtra(CastMediaControlIntent.EXTRA_CAST_RELAUNCH_APPLICATION, true);

    intent.putExtra(CastMediaControlIntent.EXTRA_DEBUG_LOGGING_ENABLED, true);

    intent.putExtra(CastMediaControlIntent.EXTRA_CAST_STOP_APPLICATION_WHEN_SESSION_ENDS,
            true);

    mRoute.sendControlRequest(intent, new MediaRouter.ControlRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Bundle data) {
            super.onResult(data);

            mSessionId = data.getString(MediaControlIntent.EXTRA_SESSION_ID);
            Log.v("PlayerFragment", "Session ID is: " + mSessionId);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Application doesn't start on TV, there isn't corresponding string in logcat and debugger breakpoint in onResult method isn't caught.
Here is part of logcat

```
10-05 23:02:05.097    5740-5740/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSAPP I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1372)
10-05 23:02:05.582    5740-5740/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSAPP I/MediaRouter﹕ Found default route: MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=android/.support.v7.media.SystemMediaRouteProvider:DEFAULT_ROUTE, name=Tablet, description=null, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=0, playbackStream=3, volumeHandling=1, volume=15, volumeMax=15, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=null, providerPackageName=android }
10-05 23:02:06.074    5740-5740/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSAPP D/android.widget.GridLayout﹕ vertical constraints: y1-y0>=500, y2-y1>=32, y3-y2>=48, y4-y3>=0, y4-y0<=512 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y4-y0<=512.
10-05 23:02:06.222    5740-5740/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSAPP D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-05 23:02:06.722    5740-5740/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSAPP I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@419a2a68 time:38947645
10-05 23:02:15.863    5740-5740/shirokovoi.ChromeCastSSAPP V/PlayerFragment﹕ Route selected
```

Comment: You log snippet shows only the DefaultRoute, do you see any other route when you click on the cast icon?

Comment: Yes, I see and the last string in logcat appears when I select route

Comment: why is this new route not listed/shown in the log then?

Comment: Must it be? And my  Log.v call is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve this. 
The point is in missing EXTRA_SESSION_STATUS_UPDATE_RECEIVER in my intent. I don't know why this doesn't work without this EXTRA, but if I add it it works.